# Mongodb embedding

Tags: mongodb, csv

I'm novice to mongodb please accept my apologies if this question is rudimentary.

I was looking to embed documents in csv to places collection. I'm not sure how to do this in mongo compass.

Any help would be appreciated.

places Collection

```
{
 "_id" : 123456,
 "acceptedPaymentModes": "cash",
    "address": {
      "city": "victoria",
      "country": "Mexico",
      "state": "tamaulipas",
      "street": "frente al tecnologico"
    },
}
```

CSV file (openingHours)

```
PlaceId | hours       | days

123456  | 00:00-23:30 | Mon;Tue;Wed;Thu;Fri;
123456  | 00:00-23:30 | Sat;
123456  | 00:00-23:30 | Sun;
```

is it possible to embed the opening hours into places collection?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you looking for data model or script?

Comment: I was looking for the script to embed my csv file to places collection.

Comment: @raga, as of now I have created a new collection with the name openinghours and i have imported the data to openinghours collection. later I used the merge aggregation to merge the data. I'm not sure if that is an efficient way?

Comment: db.placeProfiles.aggregate([ { $lookup: { from:'openingHours', localField:'_id', foreignField: 'placeID', as:'openingHours'} },{$merge:{into:'placeProfiles'}} ]);

My merge command

Comment: There is no "CSV" type in either JSON or BSON.  Are you wanting to embed a string, an array of strings, or something else?